# Is it possible to update Windows from Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, dual-boot, updates

I imagine that this is probably not possible, but worth asking because I'd find it useful if it were!

I dual boot my system with Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7. Though I rarely nowadays use Windows so whenever I do have to boot into it there are always lots of updates to install and I have to wait when shutting down for these to install before I can access Ubuntu again.

So I was wondering whether it would be possible to somehow keep Windows updated in the background from Ubuntu? Is there a way to mount the Windows partition and run the Window Updater or is this way to complicated a task?

Comment: I'd imagein that would be quite hard, but maybe you can run the partition in a virtrual machine, while using ubuntu, not sure if it would mess thing up. http://www.linuxjournal.com/video/run-your-windows-partition-without-rebooting

Comment: Maybe you can download all the updates from the Microsoft website for a later windows boot and installation. The only other thing that comes to mind is a virtual machine but this could lead to hardware conflicts.

Comment: Running a Windows install in a virtual machine that normally runs on the bare metal, may very well freak out Windows because of the major change in hardware it sees. It'll probably lock and you won't be able to boot Windows any more (until you call Microsoft to pretty please unlock it).

Comment: You _can_ have a virtual machine/physical installation running from the same partition using the same files.  You just need to edit the virtual machine (alot) so that the hardware presented virtually is similar to the physical hardware (this includes editing the BIOS DMI tags) or Window's anti-piracy software will constantly ask you to re-validate windows.  The virtual-box forums have a number of how-tos for doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No that's Impossible you need to be In Windows to *update* Windows, the same way you need to be in Ubuntu to *update* Ubuntu. Unless of course you're in a Virtualmachine where the 2 systems are running at the *same time*.

Answer (score 2):

The problem there is that you have to stay on Windows for those Updates to finish downloading and be applied. So it would be a definite no. Sorry.

The only way to update Windows is to be in Windows, specially Windows 7 and using the Windows Updater. The exception would be to copy/paste the updates from another PC but I doubt that everything would work correctly at the end because of the registry information and service information applied in some updates to windows.

Comment: So.. let's say I'm in ubuntu, I can just *simply* go and open the Windows Update software and it'll update Windows While *running* Ubuntu?

Comment: Yeah just read correctly the question. Thanks Uri.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option will be to reinstall windows on virtual box then you can run both at the same time, if you have enough RAM.

I have Ubuntu 12.04 x64 with a dual boot win7. And 4GB ram. I allocated 2GB to win 7 and can run both pretty smoothly at the same time. This would solve your problem but I know its a bit of a mission to set it up.

After you will never have to boot into windows again... isn’t that a huge relive? :D